# Making changes to tables automatically created for Identity. C# MVC what to use .Net Core or Just .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am somewhat new to MVC in the Microsoft world. As I read articles about different approaches, I am now left confused. I have read articles that claim not to touch or alter these tables but then see tons of examples adding fields to them (specifically AspNetUsers). I created a cross referance table in my project to avoid altering the AspNetUsers table. Now I am left stuck because I do not know how to Register users and also add to this cross referance table with the info that is needed. It would appear that this problem would go away if I just added the field to the AspNetUsers table. I just looking for input on this. Is it common to alter this table to your needs or is it a bad approach. Also I have been building this site with asp.net framework web application, there is also Asp.net Core web application. I am building a website, not an application, am I using the right approach? Or does Microsoft use the word "Application" to confuse people. My website is very data heavy and a store. If someone would be so kind as to explain or correct my understandings it would be appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, you have *several* questions here, which isn't how Stackoverflow works. You should pick the first question that you need an answer for, edit your question down so that's the only question (including relevant bits of code) and you'll hopefully get an answer. As this question stands, it'll probably get put on hold for being too broad, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your using a code first approach, you can easily add fields to AspNetUsers by extending `IdentityUser` and this is **very** commonly done and perfectly acceptable.

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
   //whatever additional properties you need here
   public DateTime Birthdate {get; set; }
   public string Country {get; set; }
}
```

After adding this class, you will generate a migration and update your database. You should now have the additional columns in AspNetUsers to store data in.

As for you saying lots of people recommend not altering the pre-built Identity tables, I'm guessing this is a recommendation to not alter column names, delete columns, etc. since Identity depends on these columns/tables however it is a bit hard to say without you supplying a link to these opinions.

Note: From your comments, you've said you already have an `ApplicationUser.cs` class. All you need to do is add whatever new properties you'd like and generate a migration/update database

Comment: I have seen this in documentations, what you propose. However for whatever reason I do not have such class in my model folder. The only thing that is in my model folder is 'viewModel' classes. Should I just make the class and why is not in there to begin with?

Comment: It doesn't get generated for you- it's something you need to create. It's not generated for you because everything works without it and is only needed when you need to customize certain things in the default identity user (like adding additional fields). in short, yes you should create it. There is no need to add a `DbSet` for it as Identity already handles that part for you. Just create the class, add migration and update database

Comment: Okay so I added this and I am getting an error that there is already a definition for 'ApplicationUser'. This resides in a class called 'IdentityModels' as ApplicationUser : IdentityUser. I thought this is where I once made changes before in another project. ClaimsIdentity is also in this class. I am wondering if the difference is ,Net VS .Net Core? I am using .Net. Which I am still confused about what I should be using for my project...

Comment: So it sure sounds like you already have an ApplicationUser class that extends IdentityUser... so you want to add your new properties in that class instead of adding a new ApplicationUser class (since you already have one). Just add the properties in your existing class and generate a migration and update database and this is not a difference with .net core vs .net framework... extending identityuser functions the same in both

Comment: As far as if you should be using .net core or .net framework, theres a lot of information available on this.. here is some from microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server